# Read in parameters with links from textfile

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in a few lines of parameters from an textfile and format these paths.

How can I improve this code to work with less lists? I just need the final paths.

```
import os
config = open("C:\\Users\\config.txt")
content = config.readlines()
removedEnds = []
removedStarts = []
finalPaths = []

for string in content:
    removedEnds.append(string.rstrip())

for string in removedEnds:
    print(string)
    if string.find('='):
        removedStarts.append(string[(string.find('=')+1):])

for string in removedStarts:
    finalPaths.append(string.split("\\"))

for string in finalPaths:
    print(os.path.join(*string))
```

The textfile looks like this:

```
Source=C:\Users\workspace\OMDB\WebContent\app
Target=C:\Apache24\htdocs
```

Comment: Does it hold only one set of `Source` vs `Target`?

Comment: What do you consider to be the output of this code? Which variables are considered important, and which are considered temporary?

Comment: @holroy Yes only this two lines

Comment: @200_success the output should be two filepaths, I only need the final two paths at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend a completely different solution, based on dict comprehensions, which would make the code much more expressive:

```
import os
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\config.txt') as f:
    paths = dict(
        re.match('([^=]+)=(.*)', line).groups()
        for line in f if '=' in line
    )
    # Canonicalize backslashes into platform-appropriate delimiters
    paths = dict((k, os.path.join(*v.split('\\'))) for k, v in paths.items())

print(paths)
```

You would then get the output as a nice data structure:

> ```
>  {'Source': 'C:\\Users\\workspace\\OMDB\\WebContent\\app', 'Target': 'C:\\Apache24\\htdocs'}
> ```

Specifically:

- Always call `open()` in the context of a `with` block, to ensure that the file gets closed with no additional effort.
- Use `r'Raw strings'` to avoid double backslashes.
- The regular expression kind of looks like the text you are trying to match.  Also, the `(.*)` capture group will naturally exclude the trailing newline.

Comment: Nice answer, but your generator comprehension, `dict((k, os.path.join(*v.split('\\'))) for k, v in paths.items())`,
is better written as a dictionary comprehension`{k: os.path.join(*v.split('\\')) for k, v in paths.items()}`.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than creating a series of lists, you should just iterate over the lines of the file directly. You don't need to maintain state between any two lines – just process them as you get them.

A few idioms you should also note:

- Use the `with open(...)` constructions. This ensures the file is always closed, even if the script throws an exception. (Your script never closes the file.)
- Rather than using `if string.find('=')`, use `if '=' in string`.
- Rather than using `string[(string.find('=')+1):]` to get the portion after the equals sign, I think it's neater and more Pythonic to use `string.split('=', maxsplit=1)[1]`

Here's a version of the script that doesn't use any lists:

```
import os


with open('C:\\Users\\config.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '=' in line:
            path = line.split('=', maxsplit=1)[1].strip()
            components = path.split('\\')
            print(os.path.join(*components))
```

Comment: I suggest dropping the `else: continue` and finishing the `if` clause with `print(os.path.join(*path.split('\\')))`.

Comment: @200_success Yes, that's neater. Fixed.

Comment: I suggest `f` -> `f.readlines()` thay are equal but the second is more explicit

Comment: @Caridorc Using `f.readlines()` loads the entire file into memory as a list before continuing; `for line in f` only reads a line at a time. It makes little difference for small files, but there's a big performance difference for large files.

Comment: @alexwlchan you're correct, I thought `readlines` gave an iterator, well thaks for the tip :)